# How to partition using createPartition

Tags: r, r-caret

I have this data below. I am having problem partitioning this using caret's createPartition.

```
gg <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 147L, 
147L, 147L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 
193L, 193L, 193L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 196L, 196L, 
196L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 199L, 199L, 199L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 203L, 203L, 203L, 
204L, 204L, 204L, 205L, 205L, 205L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 207L, 207L, 
207L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 211L, 
211L, 211L, 212L, 212L, 212L, 213L, 213L, 213L, 214L, 214L, 214L, 
215L, 215L, 215L, 216L, 216L, 216L, 217L, 217L, 217L, 218L, 218L, 
218L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 220L, 220L, 220L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 222L, 
222L, 222L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 224L, 224L, 224L, 225L, 225L, 225L, 
226L, 226L, 226L, 227L, 227L, 227L, 228L, 228L, 228L, 229L, 229L, 
229L, 230L, 230L, 230L, 231L, 231L, 231L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 233L, 
233L, 233L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 235L, 235L, 235L, 236L, 236L, 236L, 
237L, 237L, 237L, 238L, 238L, 238L, 239L, 239L, 239L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 
54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 
59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 
63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 
67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 
89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 
93L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 
98L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 
105L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
113L, 113L, 113L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 
116L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
124L, 124L, 124L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 127L, 
127L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 131L, 
131L, 131L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 
153L, 153L, 153L, 154L, 154L, 154L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 156L, 156L, 
156L, 157L, 157L, 157L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 160L, 
160L, 160L, 161L, 161L, 161L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 
164L, 164L, 164L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 166L, 166L, 166L, 167L, 167L, 
167L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 171L, 
171L, 171L, 172L, 172L, 172L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 
175L, 175L, 175L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 178L, 178L, 
178L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 181L, 181L, 181L, 182L, 
182L, 182L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 
186L, 186L, 186L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 189L, 189L, 
189L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 133L, 
133L, 133L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 
137L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 140L, 140L, 
140L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 142L, 142L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 144L, 
144L, 144L, 241L, 241L, 241L, 242L, 242L, 242L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 
244L, 244L, 244L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 246L, 246L, 246L, 385L, 385L, 
385L, 386L, 386L, 386L, 387L, 387L, 387L, 388L, 388L, 388L, 389L, 
389L, 389L, 390L, 390L, 390L, 433L, 433L, 433L, 434L, 434L, 434L, 
435L, 435L, 435L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 437L, 437L, 437L, 438L, 438L, 
438L, 439L, 439L, 439L, 440L, 440L, 440L, 441L, 441L, 441L, 442L, 
442L, 442L, 443L, 443L, 443L, 444L, 444L, 444L, 445L, 445L, 445L, 
446L, 446L, 446L, 447L, 447L, 447L, 448L, 448L, 448L, 449L, 449L, 
449L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 452L, 452L, 452L, 453L, 
453L, 453L, 454L, 454L, 454L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 
457L, 457L, 457L, 458L, 458L, 458L, 459L, 459L, 459L, 460L, 460L, 
460L, 461L, 461L, 461L, 462L, 462L, 462L, 463L, 463L, 463L, 464L, 
464L, 464L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 466L, 466L, 466L, 467L, 467L, 467L, 
468L, 468L, 468L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 470L, 470L, 470L, 471L, 471L, 
471L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 474L, 474L, 474L, 475L, 
475L, 475L, 476L, 476L, 476L, 477L, 477L, 477L, 478L, 478L, 478L, 
479L, 479L, 479L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 247L, 247L, 247L, 248L, 248L, 
248L, 249L, 249L, 249L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 252L, 
252L, 252L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 254L, 254L, 254L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 
256L, 256L, 256L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 259L, 259L, 
259L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 261L, 261L, 261L, 262L, 262L, 262L, 263L, 
263L, 263L, 264L, 264L, 264L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 
267L, 267L, 267L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 270L, 270L, 
270L, 271L, 271L, 271L, 272L, 272L, 272L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 274L, 
274L, 274L, 275L, 275L, 275L, 276L, 276L, 276L, 277L, 277L, 277L, 
278L, 278L, 278L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 280L, 280L, 280L, 281L, 281L, 
281L, 282L, 282L, 282L, 283L, 283L, 283L, 284L, 284L, 284L, 285L, 
285L, 285L, 286L, 286L, 286L, 287L, 287L, 287L, 288L, 288L, 288L, 
289L, 289L, 289L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 291L, 291L, 291L, 292L, 292L, 
292L, 293L, 293L, 293L, 294L, 294L, 294L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 296L, 
296L, 296L, 297L, 297L, 297L, 298L, 298L, 298L, 299L, 299L, 299L, 
300L, 300L, 300L, 301L, 301L, 301L, 302L, 302L, 302L, 303L, 303L, 
303L, 304L, 304L, 304L, 305L, 305L, 305L, 306L, 306L, 306L, 307L, 
307L, 307L, 308L, 308L, 308L, 309L, 309L, 309L, 310L, 310L, 310L, 
311L, 311L, 311L, 312L, 312L, 312L, 319L, 319L, 319L, 320L, 320L, 
320L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 322L, 322L, 322L, 323L, 323L, 323L, 324L, 
324L, 324L, 325L, 325L, 325L, 326L, 326L, 326L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 
328L, 328L, 328L, 329L, 329L, 329L, 330L, 330L, 330L, 331L, 331L, 
331L, 332L, 332L, 332L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 334L, 334L, 334L, 335L, 
335L, 335L, 336L, 336L, 336L, 337L, 337L, 337L, 338L, 338L, 338L, 
339L, 339L, 339L, 340L, 340L, 340L, 341L, 341L, 341L, 342L, 342L, 
342L, 343L, 343L, 343L, 344L, 344L, 344L, 345L, 345L, 345L, 346L, 
346L, 346L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 
350L, 350L, 350L, 351L, 351L, 351L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 353L, 353L, 
353L, 354L, 354L, 354L, 355L, 355L, 355L, 356L, 356L, 356L, 357L, 
357L, 357L, 358L, 358L, 358L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 
361L, 361L, 361L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 363L, 363L, 363L, 364L, 364L, 
364L, 365L, 365L, 365L, 366L, 366L, 366L, 367L, 367L, 367L, 368L, 
368L, 368L, 369L, 369L, 369L, 370L, 370L, 370L, 371L, 371L, 371L, 
372L, 372L, 372L, 391L, 391L, 391L, 392L, 392L, 392L, 393L, 393L, 
393L, 394L, 394L, 394L, 395L, 395L, 395L, 396L, 396L, 396L, 397L, 
397L, 397L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 399L, 399L, 399L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 402L, 402L, 402L, 403L, 403L, 403L, 404L, 404L, 
404L, 405L, 405L, 405L, 406L, 406L, 406L, 407L, 407L, 407L, 408L, 
408L, 408L, 409L, 409L, 409L, 410L, 410L, 410L, 411L, 411L, 411L, 
412L, 412L, 412L, 413L, 413L, 413L, 414L, 414L, 414L, 415L, 415L, 
415L, 416L, 416L, 416L, 417L, 417L, 417L, 418L, 418L, 418L, 419L, 
419L, 419L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 421L, 421L, 421L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 
423L, 423L, 423L, 424L, 424L, 424L, 425L, 425L, 425L, 426L, 426L, 
426L, 427L, 427L, 427L, 428L, 428L, 428L, 429L, 429L, 429L, 430L, 
430L, 430L, 431L, 431L, 431L, 432L, 432L, 432L, 373L, 373L, 373L, 
374L, 374L, 374L, 375L, 375L, 375L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 377L, 377L, 
377L, 378L, 378L, 378L, 379L, 379L, 379L, 380L, 380L, 380L, 381L, 
381L, 381L, 382L, 382L, 382L, 383L, 383L, 383L, 384L, 384L, 384L, 
313L, 313L, 313L, 314L, 314L, 314L, 315L, 315L, 315L, 316L, 316L, 
316L, 317L, 317L, 317L, 318L, 318L, 318L), .Label = c("CUR:0:L1", 
"CUR:0:L2", "CUR:0:L3", "CUR:0:L4", "CUR:0:L5", "CUR:0:L6", "CUR:00A:L1", 
"CUR:00A:L2", "CUR:00A:L3", "CUR:00A:L4", "CUR:00A:L5", "CUR:00A:L6", 
"CUR:00B:L1", "CUR:00B:L2", "CUR:00B:L3", "CUR:00B:L4", "CUR:00B:L5", 
"CUR:00B:L6", "CUR:00C:L1", "CUR:00C:L2", "CUR:00C:L3", "CUR:00C:L4", 
"CUR:00C:L5", "CUR:00C:L6", "CUR:00D:L1", "CUR:00D:L2", "CUR:00D:L3", 
"CUR:00D:L4", "CUR:00D:L5", "CUR:00D:L6", "CUR:00F:L1", "CUR:00F:L2", 
"CUR:00F:L3", "CUR:00F:L4", "CUR:00F:L5", "CUR:00F:L6", "CUR:00H:L1", 
"CUR:00H:L2", "CUR:00H:L3", "CUR:00H:L4", "CUR:00H:L5", "CUR:00H:L6", 
"CUR:00I:L1", "CUR:00I:L2", "CUR:00I:L3", "CUR:00I:L4", "CUR:00I:L5", 
"CUR:00I:L6", "CUR:00J:L1", "CUR:00J:L2", "CUR:00J:L3", "CUR:00J:L4", 
"CUR:00J:L5", "CUR:00J:L6", "CUR:00K:L1", "CUR:00K:L2", "CUR:00K:L3", 
"CUR:00K:L4", "CUR:00K:L5", "CUR:00K:L6", "CUR:00L:L1", "CUR:00L:L2", 
"CUR:00L:L3", "CUR:00L:L4", "CUR:00L:L5", "CUR:00L:L6", "CUR:00N:L1", 
"CUR:00N:L2", "CUR:00N:L3", "CUR:00N:L4", "CUR:00N:L5", "CUR:00N:L6", 
"CUR:00O:L1", "CUR:00O:L2", "CUR:00O:L3", "CUR:00O:L4", "CUR:00O:L5", 
"CUR:00O:L6", "CUR:00P:L1", "CUR:00P:L2", "CUR:00P:L3", "CUR:00P:L4", 
"CUR:00P:L5", "CUR:00P:L6", "CUR:00Q:L1", "CUR:00Q:L2", "CUR:00Q:L3", 
"CUR:00Q:L4", "CUR:00Q:L5", "CUR:00Q:L6", "CUR:00R:L1", "CUR:00R:L2", 
"CUR:00R:L3", "CUR:00R:L4", "CUR:00R:L5", "CUR:00R:L6", "CUR:00T:L1", 
"CUR:00T:L2", "CUR:00T:L3", "CUR:00T:L4", "CUR:00T:L5", "CUR:00T:L6", 
"CUR:00U:L1", "CUR:00U:L2", "CUR:00U:L3", "CUR:00U:L4", "CUR:00U:L5", 
"CUR:00U:L6", "CUR:00V:L1", "CUR:00V:L2", "CUR:00V:L3", "CUR:00V:L4", 
"CUR:00V:L5", "CUR:00V:L6", "CUR:00W:L1", "CUR:00W:L2", "CUR:00W:L3", 
"CUR:00W:L4", "CUR:00W:L5", "CUR:00W:L6", "CUR:00X:L1", "CUR:00X:L2", 
"CUR:00X:L3", "CUR:00X:L4", "CUR:00X:L5", "CUR:00X:L6", "CUR:00Z:L1", 
"CUR:00Z:L2", "CUR:00Z:L3", "CUR:00Z:L4", "CUR:00Z:L5", "CUR:00Z:L6", 
"CUR:01A:L1", "CUR:01A:L2", "CUR:01A:L3", "CUR:01A:L4", "CUR:01A:L5", 
"CUR:01A:L6", "CUR:01B:L1", "CUR:01B:L2", "CUR:01B:L3", "CUR:01B:L4", 
"CUR:01B:L5", "CUR:01B:L6", "CUR:1:L1", "CUR:1:L2", "CUR:1:L3", 
"CUR:1:L4", "CUR:1:L5", "CUR:1:L6", "CUR:10:L1", "CUR:10:L2", 
"CUR:10:L3", "CUR:10:L4", "CUR:10:L5", "CUR:10:L6", "CUR:11:L1", 
"CUR:11:L2", "CUR:11:L3", "CUR:11:L4", "CUR:11:L5", "CUR:11:L6", 
"CUR:12:L1", "CUR:12:L2", "CUR:12:L3", "CUR:12:L4", "CUR:12:L5", 
"CUR:12:L6", "CUR:13:L1", "CUR:13:L2", "CUR:13:L3", "CUR:13:L4", 
"CUR:13:L5", "CUR:13:L6", "CUR:16:L1", "CUR:16:L2", "CUR:16:L3", 
"CUR:16:L4", "CUR:16:L5", "CUR:16:L6", "CUR:18:L1", "CUR:18:L2", 
"CUR:18:L3", "CUR:18:L4", "CUR:18:L5", "CUR:18:L6", "CUR:19:L1", 
"CUR:19:L2", "CUR:19:L3", "CUR:19:L4", "CUR:19:L5", "CUR:19:L6", 
"CUR:2:L1", "CUR:2:L2", "CUR:2:L3", "CUR:2:L4", "CUR:2:L5", "CUR:2:L6", 
"CUR:3:L1", "CUR:3:L2", "CUR:3:L3", "CUR:3:L4", "CUR:3:L5", "CUR:3:L6", 
"CUR:4:L1", "CUR:4:L2", "CUR:4:L3", "CUR:4:L4", "CUR:4:L5", "CUR:4:L6", 
"CUR:5:L1", "CUR:5:L2", "CUR:5:L3", "CUR:5:L4", "CUR:5:L5", "CUR:5:L6", 
"CUR:6:L1", "CUR:6:L2", "CUR:6:L3", "CUR:6:L4", "CUR:6:L5", "CUR:6:L6", 
"CUR:7:L1", "CUR:7:L2", "CUR:7:L3", "CUR:7:L4", "CUR:7:L5", "CUR:7:L6", 
"CUR:8:L1", "CUR:8:L2", "CUR:8:L3", "CUR:8:L4", "CUR:8:L5", "CUR:8:L6", 
"CUR:9:L1", "CUR:9:L2", "CUR:9:L3", "CUR:9:L4", "CUR:9:L5", "CUR:9:L6", 
"PRI:0:L1", "PRI:0:L2", "PRI:0:L3", "PRI:0:L4", "PRI:0:L5", "PRI:0:L6", 
"PRI:00A:L1", "PRI:00A:L2", "PRI:00A:L3", "PRI:00A:L4", "PRI:00A:L5", 
"PRI:00A:L6", "PRI:00B:L1", "PRI:00B:L2", "PRI:00B:L3", "PRI:00B:L4", 
"PRI:00B:L5", "PRI:00B:L6", "PRI:00C:L1", "PRI:00C:L2", "PRI:00C:L3", 
"PRI:00C:L4", "PRI:00C:L5", "PRI:00C:L6", "PRI:00D:L1", "PRI:00D:L2", 
"PRI:00D:L3", "PRI:00D:L4", "PRI:00D:L5", "PRI:00D:L6", "PRI:00F:L1", 
"PRI:00F:L2", "PRI:00F:L3", "PRI:00F:L4", "PRI:00F:L5", "PRI:00F:L6", 
"PRI:00H:L1", "PRI:00H:L2", "PRI:00H:L3", "PRI:00H:L4", "PRI:00H:L5", 
"PRI:00H:L6", "PRI:00I:L1", "PRI:00I:L2", "PRI:00I:L3", "PRI:00I:L4", 
"PRI:00I:L5", "PRI:00I:L6", "PRI:00J:L1", "PRI:00J:L2", "PRI:00J:L3", 
"PRI:00J:L4", "PRI:00J:L5", "PRI:00J:L6", "PRI:00K:L1", "PRI:00K:L2", 
"PRI:00K:L3", "PRI:00K:L4", "PRI:00K:L5", "PRI:00K:L6", "PRI:00L:L1", 
"PRI:00L:L2", "PRI:00L:L3", "PRI:00L:L4", "PRI:00L:L5", "PRI:00L:L6", 
"PRI:00N:L1", "PRI:00N:L2", "PRI:00N:L3", "PRI:00N:L4", "PRI:00N:L5", 
"PRI:00N:L6", "PRI:00O:L1", "PRI:00O:L2", "PRI:00O:L3", "PRI:00O:L4", 
"PRI:00O:L5", "PRI:00O:L6", "PRI:00P:L1", "PRI:00P:L2", "PRI:00P:L3", 
"PRI:00P:L4", "PRI:00P:L5", "PRI:00P:L6", "PRI:00Q:L1", "PRI:00Q:L2", 
"PRI:00Q:L3", "PRI:00Q:L4", "PRI:00Q:L5", "PRI:00Q:L6", "PRI:00R:L1", 
"PRI:00R:L2", "PRI:00R:L3", "PRI:00R:L4", "PRI:00R:L5", "PRI:00R:L6", 
"PRI:00T:L1", "PRI:00T:L2", "PRI:00T:L3", "PRI:00T:L4", "PRI:00T:L5", 
"PRI:00T:L6", "PRI:00U:L1", "PRI:00U:L2", "PRI:00U:L3", "PRI:00U:L4", 
"PRI:00U:L5", "PRI:00U:L6", "PRI:00V:L1", "PRI:00V:L2", "PRI:00V:L3", 
"PRI:00V:L4", "PRI:00V:L5", "PRI:00V:L6", "PRI:00W:L1", "PRI:00W:L2", 
"PRI:00W:L3", "PRI:00W:L4", "PRI:00W:L5", "PRI:00W:L6", "PRI:00X:L1", 
"PRI:00X:L2", "PRI:00X:L3", "PRI:00X:L4", "PRI:00X:L5", "PRI:00X:L6", 
"PRI:00Z:L1", "PRI:00Z:L2", "PRI:00Z:L3", "PRI:00Z:L4", "PRI:00Z:L5", 
"PRI:00Z:L6", "PRI:01A:L1", "PRI:01A:L2", "PRI:01A:L3", "PRI:01A:L4", 
"PRI:01A:L5", "PRI:01A:L6", "PRI:01B:L1", "PRI:01B:L2", "PRI:01B:L3", 
"PRI:01B:L4", "PRI:01B:L5", "PRI:01B:L6", "PRI:1:L1", "PRI:1:L2", 
"PRI:1:L3", "PRI:1:L4", "PRI:1:L5", "PRI:1:L6", "PRI:10:L1", 
"PRI:10:L2", "PRI:10:L3", "PRI:10:L4", "PRI:10:L5", "PRI:10:L6", 
"PRI:11:L1", "PRI:11:L2", "PRI:11:L3", "PRI:11:L4", "PRI:11:L5", 
"PRI:11:L6", "PRI:12:L1", "PRI:12:L2", "PRI:12:L3", "PRI:12:L4", 
"PRI:12:L5", "PRI:12:L6", "PRI:13:L1", "PRI:13:L2", "PRI:13:L3", 
"PRI:13:L4", "PRI:13:L5", "PRI:13:L6", "PRI:16:L1", "PRI:16:L2", 
"PRI:16:L3", "PRI:16:L4", "PRI:16:L5", "PRI:16:L6", "PRI:18:L1", 
"PRI:18:L2", "PRI:18:L3", "PRI:18:L4", "PRI:18:L5", "PRI:18:L6", 
"PRI:19:L1", "PRI:19:L2", "PRI:19:L3", "PRI:19:L4", "PRI:19:L5", 
"PRI:19:L6", "PRI:2:L1", "PRI:2:L2", "PRI:2:L3", "PRI:2:L4", 
"PRI:2:L5", "PRI:2:L6", "PRI:3:L1", "PRI:3:L2", "PRI:3:L3", "PRI:3:L4", 
"PRI:3:L5", "PRI:3:L6", "PRI:4:L1", "PRI:4:L2", "PRI:4:L3", "PRI:4:L4", 
"PRI:4:L5", "PRI:4:L6", "PRI:5:L1", "PRI:5:L2", "PRI:5:L3", "PRI:5:L4", 
"PRI:5:L5", "PRI:5:L6", "PRI:6:L1", "PRI:6:L2", "PRI:6:L3", "PRI:6:L4", 
"PRI:6:L5", "PRI:6:L6", "PRI:7:L1", "PRI:7:L2", "PRI:7:L3", "PRI:7:L4", 
"PRI:7:L5", "PRI:7:L6", "PRI:8:L1", "PRI:8:L2", "PRI:8:L3", "PRI:8:L4", 
"PRI:8:L5", "PRI:8:L6", "PRI:9:L1", "PRI:9:L2", "PRI:9:L3", "PRI:9:L4", 
"PRI:9:L5", "PRI:9:L6"), class = "factor")
```

I wanted to use `caret` to partition my data, so this is what I did:

```
library(caret)
train.rows<- createDataPartition(gg, p=0.7,list = FALSE)
> length(train.rows)
[1] 1440
```

However, I am getting everything in gg in my `train.rows` even after 0.7 partitioning. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hello @New_to_R, I tried without `class = "factor"` and it worked fine. Just a question, why your dataset is just a vector? I mean, at least an independent and a dependent variable should be necessary if your task is predicting or classifying.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without `class = factor`

Then your partitioned vector will be:

```
indexes <- caret::createDataPartition(gg, times = 1, p = 0.7, list=FALSE)
train <- gg[indexes]
test <- gg[-indexes]
```

Comment: I used `length(indexes)` and throws `1008` which is 70% of the vector.